# Silverstripe: Dataobject in Siteconfig output in template

Tags: has-many, silverstripe, data-objects

I have a problem similar described on the silverstripe problem: [http://www.silverstripe.org/dataobjectmanager-module-forum/show/19853][1]

I have a working DataObject, wich mainly provides a Title, Caption and Image.
This goes in an has_many, which should provide a slider in the template output.

The CMS part is all done, meaning I can add multiple 'slides' from a tab in the SiteConfig.
Only the output in the template won't seem te happen.

For the codes I use:

**SingleSlide extends DataObject:**

```
public function getCMSFields_forPopup()
{
    return new FieldSet(
        new ImageUploadField('SlideImg', 'Afbeelding van slide'),
        new TextField('SlideTitle'),
        new TextField('SlideCaption'),
        new SimpleSiteTree('SlideLinkID')
    );
}
```

**In SiteConfigOverride**

```
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.SliderA', new ComplexTableField(
        $this->owner, 'SliderA', 'SingleASlide',
        array('SlideImg' => 'Afbeelding van slide', 'SlideTitle' => 'Titel van Slide', 'SlideCaption' => 'Tekst bij slide', 'SlideLink.Title' => 'Link naar pagina'
    )));
```

All left to do is be able to get the Output from here in the template.
Any help would be great!

Regards,

Kay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function to the Page_Controller class in Page.php such as below

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
   ...
      function SingleSlideList() {
         return DataObject::get('SingleSlide');
      }
   ...
}
```

Then in your ss file, you can use something like the following:

```
<% control SingleSlideList %>
    <div class="Image"><% control SlideImg %><% control CroppedImage(880,493) %><img src="$BaseHref$Filename.XML" height="$Height" width="$Width"><% end_control %><% end_control %></div>
    <div class="Content">
        <h2>$SlideTitle</h2>
        <p>$SlideCaption</p>
        <p><a href="$SlideLinkID.Link">my link</a></p>
    </div>
<% end_control %>
```

you will need to change the html to work with what you need.